# How to get a string array element from JSON?

Tags: android, arrays, json, kotlin

I have a JSON file from the server in which all the fields are strings. But the image field is an array of strings. How do I get all the elements of this array to display in the recyclerview?

My First Json

```
{
  "_id": "5e1063a9688c775700025bcb",
  "firstName": "Armen",
  "lastName": "Mkhitaryan",
  "phone": 37493055062,
  "email": "armdev19@gmail.com",
  "notes": "Android Developer",
  "images": [
    "https://phonebookapp-683c.restdb.io/rest/images"
  ]
}
```

Array images

```
{
  "1": [
    "5e105996688c775700025b35",
    "5e105afd688c775700025b45",
    "5e105b11688c775700025b47",
    "5e105b2c688c775700025b4c",
    "5e105b35688c775700025b4e",
    "5e105b44688c775700025b50"
  ],
  "_id": "5e1065bf688c775700025bf4",
  "_created": "2020-01-04T10:15:27.375Z",
  "_changed": "2020-01-04T10:15:27.375Z",
  "_createdby": "maajob2012@gmail.com",
  "_changedby": "maajob2012@gmail.com",
  "_version": 0
}
```

My model

```
data class Contacts(

    @SerializedName("firstName")
    val firstName: String,
    @SerializedName("lastName")
    val lastName: String,
    @SerializedName("phone")
    val phone: String,
    @SerializedName("email")
    val email: String,
    @SerializedName("notes")
    val notes: String,
    @SerializedName("images")
    val images: List<String>
)
```

My Recycler Adapter

```
class ContactsViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var mContactIcon: CircleImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_image)
        var mContactFirstName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_first_name)
        var mContactPhone: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_phone)
        //var mContactLastName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_last_name)

        fun bind(contactsModel: Contacts) {
            contactsModel.images.toString().let { url ->
                Picasso.with(itemView.context).load(url).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_person_placeholder)
                    .into(mContactIcon)
            }

            mContactFirstName.text = contactsModel.firstName
            mContactPhone.text = contactsModel.phone
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does **Array images** do here? Didn't  understand it, can you clear?

Answer (score 0):

```
contactsModel.images.let { url ->
            Picasso.with(itemView.context).load(url[0]).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_person_placeholder)
                .into(mContactIcon)
        }
```

try this

Comment: does images var having value

Comment: Not var, value val

Comment: above JSON are different ?